# Poisson process - exponential distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose that people immigrate into a territory at a Poisson rate α = 1 per day.

Find the probability that less than 2 immigrants arrive on 1 Jan, given that there are 3 immigrants from 1 Jan to 4 Jan. The answer is 0.8436

I have found that the probability for 3 immigrants from 1 Jan to 4 Jan is 0.1954, but can't think of the next step.

Comment: I am sorry my previous answer was wrong, not just numerically but conceptually

Comment: I have added a new answer which agrees with your results upto 3 digits

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Poisson}(k,\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$
$$C = \text{3 arrived between 1 and 4}$$
$$E(i) = \text{i people arrive on Jan 1}$$

$$P(E(i<2)|C ) = \frac{P(C  \cap E(i<2))}{P(C)} $$
You have already found $P(C)$
$$P(C  \cap E(i<2)) = P(E(0)\cap C) + P(E(1)\cap C)$$
$$P(E(0)\cap C) = \text{Poisson}(0,1)*\text{Poisson}(1,1)*\text{Poisson}(1,1)*\text{Poisson}(1,1)+ 6*\text{Poisson}(0,1)*\text{Poisson}(2,1)*\text{Poisson}(1,1)*\text{Poisson}(0,1) + 4*\text{Poisson}(0,1)*\text{Poisson}(3,1)*\text{Poisson}(0,1)*\text{Poisson}(0,1)$$

$$P(E(1)\cap C) = 3*\text{Poisson}(1,1)*\text{Poisson}(1,1)*\text{Poisson}(1,1)*\text{Poisson}(0,1)+ 3*\text{Poisson}(1,1)*\text{Poisson}(2,1)*\text{Poisson}(0,1)*\text{Poisson}(0,1)$$
$$P(C  \cap E(i<2)) = P(E(0)\cap C) + P(E(1)\cap C) = 0.1648$$

$$P(E(i<2)|C ) = \frac{P(C  \cap E(i<2))}{P(C)}  = 0.8434$$